# Is there an “official”/standard CSS3 gradient syntax?

Tags: css, standards, gradient

I know there is `-webkit-gradient` and `-moz-linear-gradient`. But what is the standard way of defining a gradient?

Like there is: `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` and the standard is meant to be `border-radius`.

Comment: Here is the standard syntax, which is now adopted by IE10, FF16+ and Opera12+ (Webkit soon to follow, as of Dec '12): http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An update for 2011, the [Mozilla syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_gradients) is now the 'official' one, [adopted](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/#gradients) by the [CSS3 Image Values and Replaced Content Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217). [Webkit has been updated](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/) to use this syntax too, and this has now been incorporated into the latest versions of Chrome and Safari.

Comment: New syntax is supported in latest revs of Safari and Chrome (yah)

Answer (score 4):

Not yet, the two examples you provided are the only coded gradients available as yet, as far as I know. Most CSS3 improvement is documented on [CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/)

Answer (score 2):

It's good thing no browser has yet "standardized" on a `linear-gradient` syntax yet, since it changed between February 2011 and January 2012:

From **CSS Image Values and Replaced Content Module Level 3**

> [W3C Working Draft 17 February 2011](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/#linear-gradients)
>
> **5.1.1. ‘linear-gradient()’ syntax**
>
> ```
> <linear-gradient> = linear-gradient(
> [ 
>   [ [top | bottom] || [left | right] ] 
>   | 
>   <angle>
> ,]? 
> <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+
> );
> ```
>
> [W3C Working Draft 12 January 2012](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-images-20120112/#linear-gradients):
>
> **4.1.1. linear-gradient() syntax**
>
> ```
> <linear-gradient> = linear-gradient(
>   [ [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ] ,]? 
>   <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+
> )
> ```

To answer your question:

> No, there is no *standard* way to specifying gradients.

This is because there is no standard

And even if you assume **the** "standard" is the "standard" that **was** in effect when you asked the question, then no browser supports the "standard" because the "standard" changed and no browser supports the new standard.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson! We need a news paper to keep up with gradient syntax.

Comment: It may be not a standard yet since it haven't reached the W3C Recommendation status, but it still is more or less 'official' because it is a part of the 'official' W3C spec:)