# CSS3 gradient reference

Tags: css

I'm trying to find a good, current css3 gradient reference, including vendor prefixes.

I've gone through a number of online generators, but they seem to emit very different css rules. It's hard to say what is current / supported on current and older browsers.

**Edit**

By reference, I mean reputable, accurate websites that cover this topic.

Sorry folks, this should probably be closed.

[Is there an “official”/standard CSS3 gradient syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621632/is-there-an-official-standard-css3-gradient-syntax?rq=1)

Not sure how I didn't find this first.

Comment: `Ctrl+F`, `?`. I don't see a question here.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by reference?

Comment: I generally dislike when people make statements and never actually ask a question in the *question* they post.

Comment: @zzzzBov, so you know what I'm asking, but you're just being pedantic? That is not necessary. I've spent a lot of time on here helping others.

Comment: @ScottE, the amount of time you've spent on [SO] is irrelevant. Questions typically involve asking a question, and you should know better than to bother with a closing statement in a post.

Comment: For all you purists, the question at hand is: Can someone identify some good, current css3 gradient references, that include vendor prefixes **?** If we can now get back on topic....

Comment: For CSS related stuff I usually find CSS Tricks to be a great resource, here's an article of theirs on gradients http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another cool CSS3 gradient generator that will allow you to learn by visually tweaking things.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

They also link to several sources of CSS3 gradient documentation in their "About" section.

- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient)
- [Safari and Chrome (Webkit)](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/)
- [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/css/imagevalues/#gradients)

Comment: Great suggestion - go right to the vendors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a css3 gradient generator you can use ***voithos*** solution or

- http://gradients.glrzad.com/
- http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

But if you want a "how to use it" you can read [the documentation at mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient).

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, I also recommend reading the MDN docs.

Answer (score 1):

http://css3please.com/ is pretty good - and it allows you to fiddle with the CSS interactively.

Comment: ouch, touch on the eyes! It doesn't seem to have a good overview of different stops, nor radial gradients.